# Middle name misspelled on the Netherlands short stay visa

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, vfs-global

I recently got the shortstay visa approved for my mother for her travel to the Netherlands.
I observed that the visa stamp has a spelling mistake. Whose responsibility is it to correct this? Netherlands embassy in India or Vfsglobal, Mumbai where visa was filed?
After calling VFS, they said embassy has to do it.

How many days does it take to get this corrected? There are 3 weeks for the travel.

Any help, contact numbers, email id for reaching out to the concerned party will be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Best, Sanket

Comment: Have you seen the Consulate [contact info](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/contact/embassies-consulates-general/india/consulate-general-mumbai)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I called here but the number doesn't go through. Then I called on the foreign affairs number given there and they told me it is vfsglobal's responsibility. After calling vfsglobal, they said the embassy has to do it. So it is all confusing and not sure what is the procedure here.

Comment: Did you try to send a Whatsapp message?